# Simple ListView databinding issue

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I guess there is something trivial I am overlooking here. The Window has a DataContext and everything else in the window databinds nicely. The same RecentItems is also databound to a Menu without any problems.

My XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RecentItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>◾ <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=Command}"><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"/></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

WPF renders:

[image: Rendered XAML]

I should perhaps also mention the ListView is embedded inside a FlowDocument via a BlockUIContainer.

EDIT: I changed the XAML so that I use a Run inside the TextBlock instead - I can understand a nested TextBlock is not a good idea (although then I expect a runtime error at least) - but that gives me another binding error saying that I cannot bind to a readonly property - even if I change the Mode to OneWay.

Comment: It looks like `Header` is a `StackPanel`. Why do you need to bind to list of UI controls? This not something that you would normally do. Besides `TextBlock.Text` is of a `string` type and will accept only text.

Comment: You are quite right. I missed that the bound path is indeed a UIElement, which was useful for the Menu scenario but not here. I changed it now and my error changed as well: cannot bind to a readonly property.

Comment: Well, I don't know why but binding with Mode=OneTime solved that remaining issue. Thanks for the help dkozl!